# Json is not getting any of the fields with annotations in pojo class - Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

It is getting only name out of all the fields. Please see the below class.

Below are Hibernate Annotations

```
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="project" , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Request URL: http://localhost:8089/appln/allProjects

**JSON Response**

```
[{"name":"XYZ"},{"name":"Abc"}]
```

Comment: An error message log output etc. would be helpful otherwise I need to take a look into my crystal ball...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed getters and setters. To get fields in Json data, either the fields has to be public or their getters has to be public.